# A simple User class

Tags: beginner, php, object-oriented, database, orm

```
// The DataLayer to MySQL
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/api/DAL/classes/User.dal.php";

class User
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $age;

    public function __construct($id = null)
    {
        $this->dl = new UserDAL();

        // Get an existing user object
        if (!empty($id)) {
            $user       = $this->getUsers($id);
            $this->id   = $user->id;
            $this->name = $user->name;
            $this->age  = $user->age;
        }
    }

    public function create($user)
    {
        // Create new user
        $this->name = $user->name;
        $this->age  = $user->age;
        return $this->dl->create($user);
    }

    public function update($user)
    {
        // Update existing user
        $this->id   = $user->id;
        $this->name = $user->name;
        $this->age  = $user->age;
        return $this->dl->update($user);
    }

    public function delete($user)
    {
        // Create new user
        $this->id = $user->id;
        return $this->dl->delete($user);
    }

    public function getUsers($id)
    {
        return $this->dl->getUsers($id);
    }

}

// Some tests...

// Get existing user
$existing_user = new User("1");
var_dump($existing_user);

// Create a new user
$new_user = new User();
$new_user->age = 23;
$new_user->name = "Bob";
$new_user->create($new_user);
var_dump($new_user);

// Update existing user
$update_user = new User();
$update_user->id = "1";
$update_user->name = "Henry";
$update_user->age = 100;
$update_user->update($update_user);
var_dump($update_user);

// Delete a user
$delete_user = new User();
$delete_user->delete("1");
```

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post your `User.dal.php` too, as that would make this a more interesting question.

Comment: Comment your code/methods/properties/everything. Seriously. In your `getUsers()` method, is the `$id` argument/value an array or integer I know it's not an array)? I ask because `getUsers()` implies that you're returning multiple user**s**, not just one. Otherwise it'd be named `getUser()` See the discrepancy and potential confusion?

Answer (score 3):

The [comment by mferly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/130061/a-simple-user-class#comment244774_130061) is very constructive:

> Comment your code/methods/properties/everything. Seriously. In your `getUsers()` method, is the `$id` argument/value an array or integer I know it's not an array)? I ask because `getUsers()` implies that you're returning multiple user**s**, not just one. Otherwise it'd be named `getUser()` See the discrepancy and potential confusion?

The source of the `getUsers()` method from the class stored at `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/api/DAL/classes/User.dal.php"` was not included so we can only guess as to how it functions.

I'd also suggest considering following the singleton pattern with respect to how the `dl` property is created in the constructor for each instance:

> ```
>     $this->dl = new UserDAL();
> ```

Even if instances of that class are not very demanding of resources it may still be beneficial to reduce the number of instances as much as possible for other reasons. Does each instance of the DAL create a connection to the database? If so, that may be an important reason to minimize the number of instances.